# College Level Probability Practice Problem Website

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request

Hello I am looking for a website that gives good college level Intro to Probability practice problems on counting sample events in sample spaces and calculating the probability of various events(e.g. poker hands, lock combinations, birthday problem, etc). Or at least something with a vast number of examples that explains them. The book we use for class only had 4.

Comment: Try https://www.probabilitycourse.com.

Comment: You could always get a different probability book - if you have access to an academic/math library, you could see what they have.